# Como puedo manejar este error sqlite?

Tags: android-studio, sqlite, android-sqlite

Tengo una clase `BD` padre:

```
public class DB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int VERSION_BASEDATOS = 1;
private static final String NOMBRE_BASEDATOS = "DB.db";
private Context context;

public DataExpoAuto(Context context) {
    super(context, NOMBRE_BASEDATOS, null, VERSION_BASEDATOS);
    this.context = context;

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase 
    db.execSQL(TFavorito.create);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int 
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TFavorito.TAG);
    onCreate(db);
}

@Override
public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
}

public Context getContext() {
    return context;
}

public void setContext(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
```

Luego para crear tablas separadas hago herencia:

```
public class TFavorito  extends DB{

public static final String TAG = TFavorito.class.getSimpleName().toLowerCase();

public static final String[] array={"id","titulo","descripcion","tipo"};

public static final String create= "CREATE TABLE "+TAG+" ( "+array[0]+" INTEGER, "
        +array[1]+" TEXT NOT NULL, "+array[2]+" TEXT NOT NULL, "+array[3]+" INTEGER );";


private static TFavorito INSTANCE = null;

// creador sincronizado para protegerse de posibles problemas  multi-hilo
// otra prueba para evitar instanciación múltiple
private synchronized static void createInstance(Context context) {
    if (INSTANCE == null) {
        INSTANCE = new TFavorito(context);
    }
}

public static TFavorito getInstance(Context context) {
    if (INSTANCE == null) createInstance(context);
    return INSTANCE;
}

public TFavorito(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public void insertar(Favorito favorito){

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    if (db != null) {
        db.insert(TAG, null, favorito.getContentValues(array));
        Log.d(TAG, "Inserto correctamente "+TAG);
    }
    db.close();

}

public Favorito leer(int id,int tipo) {
    Favorito favorito = null;

    String selection =  array[0]+" = ? AND "+array[3]+" = ?";
    // Specify arguments in placeholder order.
    String[] selectionArgs = {String.valueOf(id),String.valueOf(tipo)};

    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.query(TAG, array, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null, null);

    if((c != null)&& c.moveToFirst()) {
        favorito = new Favorito();
        favorito.parceObaject(c);
        Log.d(TAG, "Recupero correctamente "+TAG);
        c.close();
    }
    db.close();
    return favorito;
}
```

Inserta bien los datos y recupera bien, pero cuando consulto datos que no hay en la tabla sale el error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.developerdj.expoauto/com.developerdj.expoauto.vista.activity.ConcesionariaActiviy}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: tfavorito (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT id, titulo, descripcion, tipo FROM tfavorito WHERE id = ? AND tipo = ?
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                              Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: tfavorito (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT id, titulo, descripcion, tipo FROM tfavorito WHERE id = ? AND tipo = ?
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1238)
                                                 at com.developerdj.expoauto.data.TFavorito.leer(TFavorito.java:65)
```

Comment: El error especifica que no existe tal tabla dentro de tu base de datos. Simplemente estas tratando de realizar una operación en tabla que no existe. Agrega otra versión o elimina los datos de la aplicación.

Comment: ¿Que tiene que ver este problema con la etiqueta 'android-studio'?

Answer (score 0):

El error que mencionas se debe a que existe una version de la base de datos con estructuras de tablas creadas las cuales no pueden ser modificadas. En este caso se creo la base de datos pero sin la tabla que necesitas.

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table:
>   tfavorito (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT id, titulo, descripcion,
>   tipo FROM tfavorito WHERE id = ? AND tipo = ?

Como opción es eliminar los datos de la aplicación o simplemente borrarla y subirla nuevamente para que se cree la nueva base de datos con las tablas requeridas.

Pero recuerda que en producción, puedes necesitar modificar la estrucutura de alguna tabla y no es opción que los usuarios realicen la eliminación de la aplicación o sus datos.

Para esto es precisamente cambiar la versión de la base de datos y vuelva a llamar el método `onUpgrade()`    que precisamente realiza un Drop de la tabla y la creación de la nueva estructura:

```
public class DB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int VERSION_BASEDATOS = 2; //***
private static final String NOMBRE_BASEDATOS = "DB.db";
private Context context;

public DataExpoAuto(Context context) {
    super(context, NOMBRE_BASEDATOS, null, VERSION_BASEDATOS);
    this.context = context;

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int 
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TFavorito.TAG);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Comment: Hola puedes me puedes dar mas referencia para poder mejorar o enlaces o ejemplos de como se debe manejar una BD con sqlite.

Comment: Claro que si, el tutorial de nuestros amigos de hermosa programación es excelente  http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2014/10/android-sqlite-bases-de-datos/

Answer (score 0):

suppose that your database is not created because execSQL doesn't return a value. The error says 'no such table'. On your insert method check the value returned by 'insert' statement, check it's not it's not -1.

Comment: Estás en SOes por la que tu respuesta debe estar en español. Por favor edita la respuesta para adaptarla a dicho idioma.